# How to acquire number of times a value is found in several columns

Tags: sql, multiple-columns

I have seen similar questions on this page but they don't seem to have an answer for my problem. This is a training exercise that I am trying to solve.

In this exercise I have two tables. First table holds information about files that are identified by `unique ID`.

Second table holds information about storage devices, each device has a name and five slots for files(each slot for one file).

Each file can be written to multiple devices and even the samae device several times, device can have empty spaces.

Table looks something like this:

```
devices  | slot1 | slot2 | slot3 | slot4 | slot5
---------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------
device1  | file1 | file2 | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  
device 2 | file4 | file1 | file4 | file5 | NULL
```

and so on (`file1`, `file2`... file ID's from first table)

My problem is that I can't think of a way to find how many times in total  a file has been written to a device.

in this example I would like to get a table like this:

```
file1 | 2  
file2 | 1  
file4 | 2  
file5 | 1
```

how do I do it?

I have tried differente approaches using `COUNT` for each slot then somehow uniting them but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select files, count(*) from (
    select slot1 as files from your_table where slot1 is not null
    union all
    select slot2 from your_table where slot2 is not null
    union all
    select slot3 from your_table where slot3 is not null
    union all
    select slot4 from your_table where slot4 is not null
    union all
    select slot5 from your_table where slot5 is not null
) sq
group by files
```